# How to publish an LXC image to a private server

Tags: lxc, image, containers

I have set up a development environment in a container that I want to share with co-workers.

I set up a server and configured it with `lxc remote add the_server_name 192.168.1.99 --public`, being that the server name and IP.

What is the correct on my development machine to create the image and publish it to that server?

I do not want it to be shared to a public server.

My development machine is: Ubuntu 16.04.1, running lxc version 2.5, and the server is an Ubuntu 16.10, running lxc 2.4.1

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/06/30/publishing-lxd-images/

I was under the impression that "publish" would produce an iso image or equivalent, but doesn't seem to be the case. However, seems to be what you're after from the description. Haven't tried it myself though. Would have added as a comment, but not able to do that yet.